# How to install .Net 4.6.2 on windows 2012r2

Tags: windows, .net, dism

We have hundreds of IIS web servers with .Net 3.x and 4.0 installed using using dism.exe on windows 2012r2 (via chef)

powershell command

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX4
```

chef resource

```
windows_feature 'NetFx4' do
  action :install
end
```

This only installs up to 4.6.0

```
gci 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse | gp -name Version,Release -EA 0 | where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | select PSChileName, Version, Release


PSChildName                      Version        Release
-----------                      -------        -------
v2.0.50727                       2.0.50727.4927
v3.0                             3.0.30729.4926
Windows Communication Foundation 3.0.4506.4926
Windows Presentation Foundation  3.0.6920.4902
v3.5                             3.5.30729.4926
Client                           4.6.01055      394271
Full                             4.6.01055      394271
Client                           4.0.0.0
```

How can I install .net 4.6.2 though dism on Windows 2012r2?

**Update**

Those voting to close, please explain why. This question clearly fits the description of questions that can be asked

> managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these deployment to and management of third-party provided information
>   technology platforms

Answer (score 1):

Your DISM command is just enabling the .Net feature already installed on the OS. DISM can install update packages, but .Net is an .exe installer. So I don't think you can do install it with DISM. You would be best off [grabbing the offline installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53344) and using the `/q` and `/norestart` flags.